# C# WinForms PING Works in debugger with command line parameters but not when manually launched

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, active-directory, ping

If I launch my app without command line parameters, then supply a computer to connect to, everything works ok.

If I configure debug mode with a command line parameter, and launch the application, it works ok.

If I launch the application with command line parameters outside of visual studio, then there are issues...

If I do not Ping the machine to make sure that it is there (passed on the command line) by commenting out the code that does it, there are no issues...

If I leave it the code to ping a machine, I have issues when running from the command line with parameters...

I get the same issues if I search AD for the machine...

The errors I am getting from ping appears to be a DNS issue as it returns host not found.

The errors I am getting from the AD check is Network path not found.

I have launched a "MessageBox.Show("\""+Host\"\"");" just before doing the check and the parameter being passed is correct.

Any ideas?

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and compiling using AnyCPU and .Net 4.6.1

Here is my PingComputer and ComputerExistsInAD code:

```
    public static bool PingComputer(string SystemName, int Timeout = 5000)
    {
        try { return (new Ping()).Send(SystemName, Timeout).Status == IPStatus.Success; } catch { }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ComputerExistsInAD(string SystemName)
    {
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
            ComputerPrincipal Principal = new ComputerPrincipal(Context);
            Principal.Name = SystemName;
            PrincipalSearcher Searcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
            Searcher.QueryFilter = Principal;
            return Searcher.FindOne() != null;
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You say you use `MessageBox.Show(Host);` but in your code I don't see a variable `Host` only `SystemName`. Are you sure they are the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same...  Tried MessageBox in several places...  Then added one jusr to allow me to attach the debugger to the process so I could step through the code a line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with .Net 4.6.1...  I went back to 4.5.2, and now it works without any other changes...